# Covering function's graph with countably many sets of Lebesgue measure $0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We have a uniformly continous function on an interval $[0,1]$. How to show that we can cover its graph with countably many sets, each one of Lebesgue measure equal to $0$?

Comment: Are you covering the *interval*, or covering the *function*? By covering the function do you mean covering its graph?

Comment: What do you mean by covering the functions?

Comment: I'm sorry I just edited the question, I meant covering its graph.

Comment: The graph itself is of measure zero, so I don't see any issue. Maybe you're asked to prove that for every $\epsilon > 0$, you can cover the graph with countably many rectangles such that the sum of their areas is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Well my task is to prove that graph has measure $0$ and my question is what I still lack in my proof.

Comment: I would go about that differently: By uniform continuity you can create, for every $n$, a measurable set $U_n$ of measure less than $1/n$ containing the graph in such a way that $U_n \supseteq U_{n+1}$ for all $n$. This implies that the graph has measure $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Every measurable function have graph of measure zero because uncountable union of all its vertical translation will give $[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}$. Which is impossible because $[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}$ is $\sigma$-finite.

To get the desired representation note that
$$
\operatorname{Graph}(f)=\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\operatorname{Graph}\left(f|_{[2^{-n},2^{1-n}]}\right)
$$

Comment: Very nice argument!

Comment: Although I feel Graph($f$)=RHS is overkill.  Simply note that because the Graph is itself measure zero, you can "cover the graph with itself" which is of course a countable operation, since you do it once!

Comment: I understand, but I OP was interested with countable caver by non-empaty disjoint sets.